# Should i use the or not and why?

Tags: definite-article

> So I made tacos on match night.

OR

> So I made tacos on **the** match night.

(Here the use of article is necessary if yes,then please explain)

Comment: No, because "match night" is a set phrase acting almost as a proper noun (compare "I made tacos on Tuesday").

Comment: I agree with Daniel Roseman.  *night* is a countable noun that needs some kind of determiner, but "match" acts like a determiner here.

Answer (score 2):

The thing here is that "match night" can be used to mean a generic "night on which matches happen", and so could be taken to mean a general instance of a generic collection of such nights.

Hence:

- "I made tacos on match night"
  can be interpreted as: "During that phase of my life, when match night came along, I would habitually make tacos."

On the other hand:

- "I made tacos on the match night"
  would specifically mean: "On the night that the match was held (in that particular instance), I made tacos."

However, in the second instance, one would write:

- "So I made tacos on the night of the match."

On the *other* other hand, if you *were* only talking about one particular night, and indeed there is only one night when a match was held, you *would* be more likely to write:

- "So I made tacos on match night."